# Windows external hard drive boot loader accidentally deleted while trying to dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I was trying to figure out which of my drives was which before I partitioned it so I could dual boot windows and Ubuntu. while doing this I stupidly decided to delete a partition on my external hard drive that has games on it this hard drive does not contain windows it's self, but was initially created through windows and is NTFS. I realized quickly after that this was an awful idea, and now I cannot access my hard drive that contains my games.

Any advice on how to gain access to my hard drive again without having to lose all my data is very welcome

Thanks

picture of Gparted showing my data still exists on the drive but that the partition usually containing the boot-loader is unallocated(because I accidentally deleted it) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lID9I.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it by re-mounting it, I was completely wrong, there was no "bootloader" as this drive did not contain an OS, I simply deleted the mountpoint, which I was able to fix by re-mounting with the command `sudo mkdir /mnt/<drive label>`
I hope my blunder and fix will be able to help someone else in the future